# Align img to bottom of Jumbotron in Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Using Bootstrap 3 and the Jumbotron from the example templates, I have this:

```
<div class="jumbotron" style="margin-bottom:0px; background:url('/img/bgimg.jpg') white no-repeat; min-height:450px;">
    <div class="container">
        <img src="img/logo.png" class="img-responsive center-block" style="opacity:0.8;">
    </div>
</div>
```

I want the inner image (logo.png) to be pulled down to the bottom of the Jumbotron.

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you create a bootply or jsFiddle example?

Answer (score 0):

Use css position, like this:

```
<div class="jumbotron" style="margin-bottom:0px; background:url('/img/bgimg.jpg') white no-repeat; min-height:450px; position: relative;">
    <div class="container">
        <img src="img/logo.png" class="img-responsive center-block" style="opacity:0.8; position: absolute; bottom: 0;">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I actually tried this. The problem is that the container becomes too wide on small displays, and flows over the right edge.

Comment: Is possible to see somewhere the code? In fiddle is impossible to use bootstrap but you can try Codepen?